# Open a .tex file, modify it in MATLAB, and then save it in a .tex file again (+ possibly compile it)

Tags: matlab

[This question requires the knowledge of both tex and MATLAB, and probably this is not the write place to ask it, but maybe someone has experience of both these program and can come up with an idea]

Let's say I have a tex file, say MWE.tex, whose content is

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{report}
  \RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
  \RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks}  
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

  \begin{document}
  In this report we use x = VARX and y = VARY.
  \end{document}
```

I would like to open in MATLAB, substitute VARX and VARY with values that come from some functions and save them in another .tex file. For instance VARX is the result of randi(10) and VARY is the result of randi(5).

What's the simplest solution to do this?

Would it also be possible to launch the latex compiler from Matlab? How?

Comment: Why don't you just have matlab output a file containing VARX and VARY and read it using pgfplotstable?  Or have it write \varx{3e8} etc. to be read by \input.  I believe siunitx or pgfmath will convert 3e8 appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses MATLAB, where you run the script

```
text = fileread('MWE.tex');
newtext = strrep(text,'VARX',num2str(randi(10)));    
newtext = strrep(newtext,'VARY',num2str(randi(5)));    

fileID = fopen('newMWE.tex','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s',newtext);
fclose(fileID);

command = 'pdflatex newMWE.tex';
[status,cmdout] = system(command)
```